# In geonodes, using Extrude Mesh leaves an open face opposite the extruded normal. How to best fill it?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When using geometry nodes' Extrude Mesh node, the bottom side or the opposite side of the extruded face becomes open. What is the best practice in filling it? I normally just use another Extrude and have a value of 0 and then use another node called "Flip Faces" to fix the normals. Is there a better solution to this with one node only or this is presently considered an "ok" solution?

[image: example]

PS:
[Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86978/chris) mentioned in one of our discussions that it is fine to do and suggested that I put it as a separate question so that others may see it as well. I'm also open to seeing how others might have a different approach to this. Thanks again Chris, I learned a lot from you and the whole community.

Comment: oh wow, why didn't I think of that, I thought I would need to add the Extrude. I didn't realize I can just use the original mesh and run it on flip node. Thanks for this Gorgious! 

Comment: Sorry for the question, I didn't realize it has a duplicate. In my defence, the post never appeared on my google search nor the suggested post during authoring. I have flagged my post as duplicate 

Comment: Hello ! Don't apologize, the community is there to link all the similar questions together. ;) You have done nothing wrong. It's a pleasure to try and find a solution for well though out questions, thank you for your contribution

Comment: Thanks, Gorgious, for your patience and taking the time to explain, I understand now. I love this community and of course Blender. I'm currently losing sleep, I chose to sleep little to spend more time playing around with Geonodes 